# Install Ubuntu 18.04.2 black screen install

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, dell

i have problem with installing Ubuntu 18.04.2 on Dell Inspiron 15z when I choice installs ubuntu gives me a black screen and stuck for this.

- i try edit mode and add nomodeset but still same

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable or change GPU drivers? Usually you can choose between proprietary and open source. If both fail, try recovery mode.
2. If you are booting from a USB stick, try reflashing with the included "USB image writer". Also, make sure that the architecture of the image matches your settings.

Comment: how disable gpu when i start install ?
i try reflashing iso , but still same

Comment: Press **tab** in the boot menu.

Comment: not working , still same error